# Как получить координаты полигона, добавленного через editor (yandex maps)?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Как в `react-yandex-maps` получить координаты всех полигонов карты или только что добавленного?

```
<YMaps>
      <Map
        height="480px"
        width="auto"
        defaultState={{ center: [defaultLat, defaultLon], zoom }}
        modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint', 'geoObject.addon.editor']}
      >
          <Polygon
            instanceRef={instanceRef}
            geometry={[]}
            options={{
              draggable: true,
              editorDrawingCursor: 'crosshair',
              strokeColor: colors.primary,
              strokeOpacity: 0.5,
              strokeWidth: 3,
            }}
          />
      </Map>
    </YMaps>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен. Refs (**instanceRef**) в помощь

```
const Map: React.FC<IMapProps> = ({
  placemarks,
  polygons: defaultPolygons,
  defaultLat = 0,
  defaultLon = 0,
  zoom = DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [isEditMode, setIsEditMode] = useState(false);
  const [polygons, setPolygons] = useState(defaultPolygons || []);
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

  const toggleIsEditMode = (): void => {
    setIsEditMode((prevIsEditable) => !prevIsEditable);
  };

  const instanceRef = useCallback((ref: any) => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.editor.startDrawing();
      ref.geometry.events.add('change', (e: any) => setCoordinates(e.get('newCoordinates')));
    }
  }, []);
  const resetCoordinates = useCallback(() => {
    setCoordinates([]);
    setIsEditMode(false);
  }, []);
  const saveCoordinates = useCallback(() => {
    setPolygons([...polygons, ...coordinates]);
    resetCoordinates();
    // @todo: to add save request
  }, [coordinates, polygons, resetCoordinates]);

  return (
    <YMaps>
      {polygons.length && (
        <Row className={styles.controls}>
          {isEditMode ? (
            <Space>
              <Button onClick={saveCoordinates}>{t('buttons.save')}</Button>
              <Button onClick={resetCoordinates}>{t('buttons.reset')}</Button>
            </Space>
          ) : (
            <Button onClick={toggleIsEditMode}>{t('buttons.addPolygon')}</Button>
          )}
        </Row>
      )}
      <YandexMap
        height="480px"
        width="auto"
        defaultState={{ center: [defaultLat, defaultLon], zoom }}
        modules={['geoObject.addon.balloon', 'geoObject.addon.hint', 'geoObject.addon.editor']}
      >
        <MapPlacemarks placemarks={placemarks} />
        <MapPolygon polygons={polygons} />
        {isEditMode && (
          <Polygon
            instanceRef={instanceRef}
            geometry={coordinates}
            options={{
              draggable: true,
              editorDrawingCursor: 'crosshair',
              strokeColor: colors.primary,
              strokeOpacity: 0.5,
              strokeWidth: 3,
            }}
          />
        )}
      </YandexMap>
    </YMaps>
  );
};
```